# Como criar ordenação personalizada?

Tags: lógica

Estou em busca de uma forma de criar um ordenador personalizado.

Digamos que eu tenha o seguinte:

```
var array = [
    1=>'A',
    2=>'B',
    3=>'C',
    4=>'D',
    5=>'E',
    6=>'F',
]
```

Agora ao invés de ordenar pelo indice ou pelo valor em ordem alfabetica ou o inverso, gostária de passar minha própria ordem. Poderia ser qualquer coisa que o usuário imagina ex:

> `ordem = acebdukl`
>    `ordem = brvdencst`

Caso o item do array não exista na ordem, o mesmo deve ir para o final.
Caso o item do array esteja repetido todas as repetições devem estar em sequência.

A linguagem de exemplo não importa, só me importo com o desenvolvimento da ideia.

Comment: E tens um objeto ou uma array como input?

Comment: @Sergio poderia ser os 2 casos e até mesmo uma String futuramente, mas no momento seria só pra objeto e pra array

Comment: E o que fazes a casos em que não existe? por exemplo `kl` na ordem que não existe no exemplo que deste de array

Comment: @Sergio deve seguir ao próximo, da mesma forma que uma ordenação alfabetica

Comment: Ok, coloquei uma resposta. Tenho de sair, se não fôr o que procuras posso ajustar depois. Provavelmente vêm aí mais respostas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que é isto que procuras: (exemplo com array)

```
var array = [
    [1, 'A'],
    [2, 'B'],
    [3, 'C'],
    [4, 'D'], [4, 'D'],
    [5, 'E'],
    [6, 'F']
];

function ordenarPor(arr, ordem) {
    return arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        var indexA = ordem.indexOf(a[1].toLowerCase());
        var indexB = ordem.indexOf(b[1].toLowerCase());
        if (indexA < 0) indexA = arr.length + 1;
        if (indexB < 0) indexB = arr.length + 1;
        return indexA > indexB;
    });
}

var nova = ordenarPor(array, 'acebdukl');
console.log(JSON.stringify(nova));

// dá: [[1,"A"],[3,"C"],[5,"E"],[2,"B"],[4,"D"],[4,"D"],[6,"F"]]
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7a9waxkx/2/

Comment: é quase isso Sergio, faltam apenas 2 fatores para serem considerados. Caso o item do array não exista na ordem deve ir para o final, e caso o item esteja repetido no array, todas as repetições devem aparecer no array final. De resto funciona perfeitamente

Comment: @RodrigoBorth ok, seria então assim? -> http://jsfiddle.net/7a9waxkx/1/

Comment: Ta quase agora, só vi que quando tenho um valor repetido e ele está para ser ordenado o mesmo só aparece 1 vez e deveria aparecer todas as repetições... o resto está ok

Comment: @RodrigoBorth essas array vão ter que tipos de variáveis? Elementos do DOM? strings? objetos/arrays simples? ou um pouco de tudo?

Comment: Serão elementos que irão pro DOM depois com o critério que o usuário quiser

Comment: @RodrigoBorth -> http://jsfiddle.net/7a9waxkx/2/

Comment: Perfeito, agora é só atualizar a resposta.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth ótimo. Juntei este último código à resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Em `python`, essas linhas resolvem seu problema:

```
string = 'acebdukl'

organizada = sum([list(filter(lambda key: key if key[1].upper() == letra else None, lista)) for letra in string.upper()], [])
organizada += [item for item in lista if item not in organizada]

print(organizada) 
>>>
[[1, 'A'], [3, 'C'], [5, 'E'], [2, 'B'], [4, 'D'], [4, 'D'], [6, 'F']]
```